# delete duplicate records without using common table expression (CTE)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know how to delete duplicate records using CTE.

How can we achieve this without using CTE [Interview Question]

Is it possible?

Example: Table with the following data:

```
name     salary
-----------------
Husain   20000.00
Husain   20000.00
Husain   20000.00
Munavvar 50000.00
Munavvar 50000.00
```

After deleting the duplicate records
table should contains data like this :

```
name     salary
-----------------
Husain   20000.00
Munavvar 50000.00
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to delete duplicate rows retaining one such row, you can do so by using ROW_NUMBER() function in SQL. Delete all rows with row number > 1. Assuming you know how ROW_NUMBER() and PARTITION works. If not you can get more information on this on msdn.

```
DELETE A
FROM
(
SELECT name,salary, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name,salary ORDER BY name) AS rn
FROM Tab
) A
WHERE A.rn > 1
```

Just a heads-up on the response from @TimSchmelter, it will delete all existence of duplicates. Be aware of the difference, you can use either as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Akanksha for response. but it also deleting all the records

Comment: No it will not. Make sure you are partitioning only with the columns that defines 'DUPLICATE' records.

Comment: yes it is deleting all rows.. please try with given example (Check question)

Comment: Are you running exactly what I have shared (now edited with your column names)? If you understand the crux, you can write column names which define duplicate rows. But this should work 100% :)

Comment: @Munavvar: i thought you need a solution without using a CTE **and** rdbms specific ranking functions like `ROW_NUMBER`. Are you sure that interviewer didn't want an ANSI sql solution which doesn't require SQL-Server >= 2005?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: interviewer asked me to delete duplicate records. I completed the query with using CTE. After that he asked me to do same without using CTE.

Answer (score 2):

With sub queries and `GROUP BY HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`.

Presuming that you want to find duplicates according to two columns `col1` and `col2`:

Query to list all duplicates:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM dbo.TableName t
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT [col1], [col2], Cnt = COUNT(*)
   FROM dbo.TableName t
   GROUP BY [col1], [col2]
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) Duplicates
ON t.[col1] = Duplicates.[col1] AND t.[col2] = Duplicates.[col2]
```

Delete them:

```
DELETE dbo.TableName
FROM dbo.TableName t
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT [col1], [col2], Cnt = COUNT(*)
   FROM dbo.TableName t
   GROUP BY [col1], [col2]
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) Duplicates
ON t.[col1] = Duplicates.[col1] AND t.[col2] = Duplicates.[col2]
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for quick response. but this will delete all the record with duplicate value. I want to delete repeated data.

Comment: @Munavvar: so all but one? Here are some approaches: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/removing-duplicates-from-a-table-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

1. [Correlated Subqueries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638(v=sql.105).aspx)
2. [Self Joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```html
select * from DuplicateRcordTable
```

[image]

```html
WITH CTE 
AS
(
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col3 ORDER BY Col3) AS DuplicateCount
FROM DuplicateRcordTable
)
DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE DuplicateCount > 1
```

```html
select * from DuplicateRcordTable2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most common use of **Common Table Expression (CTE)** is  Deleting duplicate record from table which not having Primary Key

```
WITH a as
(
SELECT A,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by A, B ORDER BY A) 
AS duplicateRecCount dbo.A
)
--Now Delete Duplicate Records
DELETE FROM A
WHERE duplicateRecCount > 1 [enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: The question from the O.P. was how to do it WITHOUT using a CTE.
Not every SQL RDBMS offers CTEs.  I know of at least two such systems.

Answer (score 0):

We can also Delete Duplicate Record from Table by Using **Cursor** or by using another lopping statements. following code spinets deletes Duplicates Record by using Cursor

```
  DECLARE @A nvarchar(50), @B nvarchar(50) , @C nvarchar(50), @TotalDuplicate INT ; 



DECLARE a_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT A, B  ,C ,COUNT(1)-1 AS TotalDuplicate
FROM A  
GROUP BY  A, B  ,C 
HAVING COUNT(1)>1

OPEN a_cursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM a_cursor INTO @A, @B,@C,@TotalDuplicate  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    DELETE TOP (@TotalDuplicate) FROM A WHERE A=@A AND B=@B AND C=@C 

    FETCH NEXT FROM a_cursor INTO @A, @B,@C,@TotalDuplicate  

END

CLOSE a_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE a_cursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *  into #temp 

from Emp_Details 

group by Name, Salary

having count(*) =1
```

Now, Truncate the original table

```
Truncate table Emp_Details
```

Again, inserting the records from temporary table to Emp_Details

```
insert Emp_Details (Name, Salary, Address)

Select Name, Age, Address from #temp
```