# Erase duplicates using substrings tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table

```
create table bufScan
(
   msgid int,
   conversationid nvarchar(max),
   mailbox nvarchar(max)
);

INSERT dbo.bufScan VALUES 
(1,'person1@company.com','AAQkAGIwZjk4OTk4LTRkZGYtNDM5Yi04NGZlLTAzMDY1MjQ3ZjVlMgAQAPX8hFCq30h3robsMxenwt8='),
(2,'person1@company.com','AAQkAGIwZjk4OTk4LTRkZGYtNDM5Yi04NGZlLTAzMDY1MjQ3ZjVlMgAQAESPK731aUirpd0CyOIlR5I='),
(3,'person1@company.com','AAQkAGIwZjk4OTk4LTRkZGYtNDM5Yi04NGZlLTAzMDY1MjQ3ZjVlMgAQAESPK731aUirpd0CyOIlR5I='),
(4,'person1@company.com','AAQkAGIwZjk4OTk4LTRkZGYtNDM5Yi04NGZlLTAzMDY1MjQ3ZjVlMgAQAPX8hFCq30h3robsMxenwt8='),
(5,'person2@company.com','AAQkADhlYTk5MGY1LTJkOTUtNDVjNy1iNDg0LTljYjc5ODAzZTM3OQAQAPX8hFCq30h3robsMxenwt8='),
(6,'person2@company.com','AAQkADhlYTk5MGY1LTJkOTUtNDVjNy1iNDg0LTljYjc5ODAzZTM3OQAQAESPK731aUirpd0CyOIlR5I='),
(7,'person2@company.com','AAQkADhlYTk5MGY1LTJkOTUtNDVjNy1iNDg0LTljYjc5ODAzZTM3OQAQAESPK731aUirpd0CyOIlR5I='),
(8,'person2@company.com','AAQkADhlYTk5MGY1LTJkOTUtNDVjNy1iNDg0LTljYjc5ODAzZTM3OQAQAX8hFCq30h3robsMxenwt8=');
```

Let us assume that `AAQkADhlYTk5MGY1LTJkOTUtNDVjNy1iNDg0LTljYjc5ODAzZTM3OQ` and `AAQkAGIwZjk4OTk4LTRkZGYtNDM5Yi04NGZlLTAzMDY1MjQ3ZjVlMg` are entries that give us information for a specific mailbox and `AX8hFCq30h3robsMxenwt8=` and `AESPK731aUirpd0CyOIlR5I=` for a specific conversation.

In this example, person1 is having conversations with person2.
I would like to keep all conversation from only one mailbox, otherwise, it will be like having double conversations in my data. That means that i would like to keep entries for `AX8hFCq30h3robsMxenwt8=` and `AESPK731aUirpd0CyOIlR5I=` either from `AAQkADhlYTk5MGY1LTJkOTUtNDVjNy1iNDg0LTljYjc5ODAzZTM3OQ` or `AAQkAGIwZjk4OTk4LTRkZGYtNDM5Yi04NGZlLTAzMDY1MjQ3ZjVlMg`. I hope I made it more specific. 
Since I want to keep also information about all messages that are part of the conversation I don't want to delete duplicates that have different message id in the same partition of the mailbox.

Comment: If that is a table, what does a column look like?  What is the name of the table?  What are the names of the columns?  Desired results would also really help.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data and desired result would helpful.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542036/delete-duplicate-records-without-using-common-table-expression-cte

Comment: What if there was a mailbox3 with zzz?

Comment: This still looks like there are duplicates, i.e. "yyyAQA111" is there twice and "yyyAQA222" also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()` function :

```
select top (1) with ties *
from table t
order by dense_rank() over (partition by substring(mailbox, 4, len(mailbox)) 
                                          order by conversationid);
```

Comment: You can't use DENSE_RANK() in an ORDER BY clause and there are other syntax problems with your query.  Also - This not account for the fact that the attributes can be different lengths

Comment: @AlanBurstein. . . How can u think we can't use Analytical function in `order by` clause ?

Comment: I stand corrected - that just blows my mind. I've been using Window Functions in SQL Server since SQL 2005 and have NEVER seen them used in an order by clause in any blog, forum or book. Even BOL has no such examples. Downvote removed, I learnt something very cool today. Bravo sir!

Comment: Thank you @Yogesh Sharma, it was really helpful!

Comment: @Yogesh Sharma, Please take a look at my edited question

Answer (score 0):

You're explanation is still a bit vague. I think this will work:

Using this sample data:

```
USE tempdb
GO

create table dbo.bufScan
(
 msgid int,
 conversationid nvarchar(max),
 mailbox nvarchar(max)
 );

INSERT dbo.bufScan VALUES 
(1,'mailbox1','xxxAQA111'),
(2,'mailbox1','xxxAQA111'),
(3,'mailbox1','xxxAQA222'),
(4,'mailbox1','xxxAQA222'),
(5,'mailbox2','yyyAQA111'),
(6,'mailbox2','yyyAQA111'),
(7,'mailbox2','yyyAQA222'),
(8,'mailbox2','yyyAQA222');
```

You could do this:

```
WITH uniquify AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.conv ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM dbo.bufScan
  CROSS APPLY 
    (VALUES (SUBSTRING(mailbox, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', mailbox), LEN(mailbox)))) f(conv)
)
SELECT msgid, conversationid, mailbox
FROM uniquify
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

Which returns:

```
msgid       conversationid   mailbox
----------- ---------------- -----------
1           mailbox1         xxxAQA111
2           mailbox1         xxxAQA111
7           mailbox2         yyyAQA222
8           mailbox2         yyyAQA222
```

You can change rn <= 2 to rn = 1 to return this:

```
msgid       conversationid   mailbox
----------- ---------------- -----------
1           mailbox1         xxxAQA111
7           mailbox2         yyyAQA222
```